# How do I create a component that generates Radio-buttons in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Can I and should i pass arrays to components in ember?

For example if I wanted to template something that renders a couple of radiobuttons with labels:

```
<label for="media">Media</label><input type="radio" name="entry.1602323871" value="media" id="media" />
<label for="guest">Guest</label><input type="radio" name="entry.1602323871" value="guest" id="guest" />
```

Could I somehow pass an array with this content and loop through it.

```
Media, media
Guest, guest
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yeah, You can pass anything to components. Just a try to the radio-buttons

```
//Basic radio Component
App.RadioButton = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName : "input",
  type : "radio",
  attributeBindings : [ "name", "type", "value", "checked:checked" ],
  click : function() {
    this.set("selection", this.$().val());
  },
  checked : function() {
    return this.get("value") === this.get("selection");
  }.property('selection')
});
Em.Handlebars.helper('radio-button',App.RadioButton);
```

**Updated** (component name should be dasherized)

Working [Radio Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/YMc6t/7/)

Comment: @KristofferNolgren It would be better you change to title to something related to radio-button as it may help others too

Comment: How do you get a value on submit?

Comment: @selvagsz ... how would this work if there are multiple sets of radio buttons and their id/values are dynamic? See: http://jsfiddle.net/SLfWD/

Comment: @Justin You need to pass the name and selection to the radios. Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/SLfWD/1/

Comment: @Justin I will find some tym and make the `Radio` component more generic sooner. Would expect this functionality will be available in ember-core

Answer (score 2):

It's now a tiny bit easier to get radio-buttons into your project (if you're using ember-cli) by using the [ember-radio-buttons addon](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-radio-buttons)

Install:

```
npm install ember-radio-buttons --save-dev
```

Usage:

```
{{radio-button value='one' checked=selectedNumber}}
{{radio-button value='two' checked=selectedNumber}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upped @selva-G's answer.

I found that using the ButtonGroup Component from [Bootstrap-for-Ember](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/dist/#/show_components/buttonGroup) is actually cleaner.
Here's what I've done:

In my view's template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="myview">
    {{bs-btn-group contentBinding="things" selectedBinding="selectedThing"}}
</script>
```

In that view's controller (which doesn't necessarily need to be an ArrayController, rather can be a generic Ember Controller):

```
App.MyviewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    things: [
        Ember.Object.create({value: 'first', title: 'First Thing'}),
        Ember.Object.create({value: 'second', title: 'Second Thing'}),
        Ember.Object.create({value: 'third', title: 'Third Thing'})
    ],
    selectedThing: 'second'
    selection: function() {
        console.log(this.get('selectedThing');
    }.observes('selectedThing')
});
```