# Radio Component in a table throws error in Ember.Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am new to ember, in reference to the answer given by @selvagsz in [How do I create a component that generates Radio-buttons in Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268764/how-do-i-create-a-component-that-generates-radio-buttons-in-ember-js/20270829#20270829),

I tried to use the radio component within a table as I have tried here [demo] http://jsfiddle.net/eL45nr06/1/

Though it gives the output correctly it shows the following error in my console when i implement the same within my application.

Is this not the correct way to define a table using components?

```
    Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The metamorph tags, metamorph-21-start and metamorph-21-end, have different parents.
The browser has fixed your template to output valid HTML (for example, check that you have properly closed all tags and have used a TBODY tag when creating a table with '{{#each}}')
```

**THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION** BUT WORKED

I tried wrapping  tbody around tr but that too didn't work.

So I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/eL45nr06/3/ and it works though i would like to know why my previous case failed.

Comment: can you provode your code and tell us how exactly use emberJs with or without any backend, ember-cli or other build tool

Comment: Try wrapping the tr inside a tbody tag.

Comment: @Stakoov I tried my code in ember starter kit from the official website without any backend !!

Comment: @blessenm that didn't work though the output is correct the error causes problems while binding other elements in my app.